# How can this merge query matching with same columns result in primary key violation?

Tags: oracle

I have a tricky issue at hand where a merge query as below :-

```
MERGE INTO table_destination D USING table_source S 
  ON (D.id = S.id AND D.name_s = S.name_s AND D.seqno = S.seqno AND D.type_s = S.type_s) 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.class_v, D.id, D.name_s, D.seqno, D.VALID, D.IFSC_CODE, D.CREATOR, D.APPROVER, D.type_s) VALUES (S.class_v, S.id, S.name_s, S.seqno, S.VALID, S.IFSC_CODE, S.CREATOR, S.APPROVER,S.type_s) 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.VALID = S.VALID
```

gives a **primary key violation** as this - `unique constraint (schema_1.TBL_BRANCH_PK1) violated`

The DDL of the destination table is as follows:-

```
 CREATE TABLE table_destination
   (    "id" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "name_s" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "seqno" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "type_s" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IFSC_CODE" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "VALID" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "CREATOR" VARCHAR2(22 BYTE), 
    "APPROVER" VARCHAR2(22 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "TBL_BRANCH_PK1" PRIMARY KEY ("id", "name_s", "seqno", "type_s")
  );
```

Clearly the Pk that is being  violated consists of the columns that are being checked for a match in the merge query.

Another thing to note is that this query can be run from two sessions at the same time, but this shall not be an issue as merge must obtain lock on the row before actually updating it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed constraint on destination table but there is no information about constraint in source table. If in source table there are two records with same key both will try to insert and constraint fails.

```
create table t1 (id number);
create table t2 (id number, constraint tpk primary key (id));
insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t1 values (1);
commit;

merge into t2
using t1
on (t2.id = t1.id)
when not matched then insert values (t1.id);

SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TPK) violated
```